# How does it look v What does it look lke

Tags: questions

When people say how does it look, I want to answer "with its eyes."  I prefer a perfectly good "What does it look like?"though I hear and read the other version all the time! Which is correct?....I have even seen and heard "How does it look like?

Comment: I am not prepared to accept "How does it look like" as correct.  The other two are both ok, but they don't mean the same thing.  The answers to the linked question go into detail.

Answer (score 1):

When asking "How does it look?", we often expect an answer of the other person's  evaluation, for example when trying on a new hat or dress. 
Example:
How does it look?
    I think it suits you.
When asking "What does it look like?", we are asking the other persons opinion on the object’s similarity with something else.
Example:
What does it look like?
    It looks like a fried egg.